# Interpolate specific spells of missing values

Tags: stata

My data is similar to the following:

```
 id   year     var
10052 1980 2264758272
10052 1981 2434758400
10052 1982 2474758400
10052 1983 2484758272
10052 1984 2404758272
10052 1985 2344758272
10052 1986          .
10052 1987          .
10052 1988          .
10052 1989          .
10052 1990 2264758272
10052 1991 2374758400
10052 1992 2364758272
10052 1993 2334758400
10052 1995 2234758400
10052 1996          .
10052 1997          .
10052 1998          .
10052 1999          .
10052 2000          .
10052 2001          .
10052 2002 2174758400
10052 2003 1994758400
10067 1980          .
10067 1981          .
```

I want to identify spells of successive missing values and interpolate those
that are `4` years or less.

The code below interpolates all missing values instead:

```
ipolate var year if missing(var)<=4 , generate(var1)
```

How can I do this in Stata?

Answer (score 0):

@Pearly Spencer has given a good direct answer to the question asked, but more information is needed to allow an even better one. The point of this answer is to expand on what is wrong with the code in the question and also to do what can't be done well in a comment, to flag related graphical technique.

`missing()` returns 1 or 0 depending on the value of its argument in each observation. You're hoping that it counts locally within a spell, but that's a long way from what it does.

As `missing()` returns 1 or 0, its results are always less than 4, so specifying that condition rules out none of the observations, as you found out. Note also that `if missing(var)` would select the missing values only, leaving `ipolate`  nothing to work with.

Incidentally, the data look very odd: e.g. modulo 1000 only two values occur, 400 and 272. Otherwise they're supposedly exact integers of the order of 2 billion. There may be some story here that makes interpolation suspect or a different kind of interpolation more appropriate. (Interpolation is much more than linear interpolation, its simplest flavour.)

With your example data, only one identifier has usable data. Here I just interpolate for that panel with no restriction on length of intervals. (Denying yourself interpolated values within longer spells of missings seems arbitrary. 
Just plot the results: sometimes they will make sense within longer intervals.)

```
bysort id: ipolate var year, generate(wanted)  

scatter var year, msymbol(Oh) || scatter wanted year if missing(var), msymbol(+) /// 
ylabel(2e9 "2" 2.2e9 "2.2" 2.4e9 "2.4", angle(horizontal)) ///
legend(ring(0) col(1) position(7)) ytitle(whatever (billions))
```

[image]

From a graph, I note:

1. No value for 1994.
2. Behaviour seems stick-and-slip, with small changes and big changes. Interpolation is going to work best with a smooth gradual change of response.